# how to get current url in nextjs without using window.location.href or react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, parse-url

how to get current url in nextjs without using window.location.href or react router

```
      const parse = require("url-parse");
      parse("hostname", {});
    
      console.log(parse.href);
```

Comment: If you're in a browser, the current URL is in `window.location.href`.  If you're not in a browser, there is no current URL.  Where do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your use case but generally as you don't have access to window object on server side you can use `getServerSideProps` and its context.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { req } = context;
  const host = req.headers.host;
  return {
    props : { host }
  }
}
```

you can utilize `useRouter` of next.js too.

```
const router = useRouter();
const { pathname } = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, you can access the current URL without using `window.location.href` or React Router by utilizing the `useRouter` hook provided by Next.js. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function Page() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const currentUrl = router.asPath;

  return (
    <div>
      Current URL: {currentUrl}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

The `useRouter` hook from `next/router` allows you to access various properties of the router, including the current URL via the `asPath` property. This method is more preferable in Next.js compared to using `window.location.href` because it works on both the client and server side without any issues.

Comment: `window.location.href` and NextJS `router.asPath` have completely different return values - `asPath` only returns the path after the host.